# scala returns doesn't conform to required S_

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I got the error

```
found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Option[models.ProcessTemplatesModel]]
required: Option[models.ProcessTemplatesModel]
```

My function is below

```
def createCopyOfProcessTemplate(processTemplateId: Int): Future[Option[ProcessTemplatesModel]] = {
    val action = processTemplates.filter(_.id === processTemplateId).result.map(_.headOption)
    val result: Future[Option[ProcessTemplatesModel]] = db.run(action)

    result.map { case (result) =>
      result match {
        case Some(r) => {
          var copy = (processTemplates returning processTemplates.map(_.id)) += ProcessTemplatesModel(None, "[Copy of] " + r.title, r.version, r.createdat, r.updatedat, r.deadline, r.status, r.comment, Some(false), r.checkedat, Some(false), r.approvedat, false, r.approveprocess, r.trainingsprocess)
          val composedAction = copy.flatMap { id =>
            processTemplates.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption
          }
          db.run(composedAction)

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

what is my problem in this case?

edit:

my controller function looks like this:

```
 def createCopyOfProcessTemplate(processTemplateId: Int) = Action.async {
    processTemplateDTO.createCopyOfProcessTemplate(processTemplateId).map { process =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(process))
    }
  }
```

Is there my failure?

Comment: You have to update the question with the function call syntax as well

Comment: added my controller function it above

Comment: `case Some(r)` is `Option` type but your result is `Future[Option[ProcessTemplatesModel]]` and thats the mistake.

Comment: what could be a solution?

Comment: It depends on what the output of `db.run(action)` is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the your code - there are the following issues:

1. You use two `db.run` which return futures, but inner future will
   not complete. For resolving it you should compose futures with
   `flatMap` or `for-comprehension`.
2. You use only one partial-function `case Some(_) =>` for pattern matching
   and don't handle another value `None`.
3. You can use only one `db.run` and actions composition.

Your code can be like as:

```
def createCopyOfProcessTemplate(processTemplateId: Int): Future[Option[ProcessTemplatesModel]] = {
    val action = processTemplates.filter(...).result.map(_.headOption)

    val composedAction = action.flatMap {
       case Some(r) =>
           val copyAction = (processTemplates returning processTemplates...)
           copyAction.flatMap { id =>
               processTemplates.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption
           }
       case _ => 
           DBIO.successful(None) // issue #2 has been resolved here
    }

    db.run(composedAction)       // issue #3 has been resolved here
  }
```

We get rid of issue #1 (because we use actions composition).